# How to log ssh debug info?

Tags: debugging, ssh, redirect

I need to write the output of ssh debug info into the file. This

```
ssh -v root@172.16.248.xx > result.txt
ssh -v root@172.16.248.xx 2>&1 > result.txt
```

doesn't work, the file result.txt is empty, but on the screen i see bunch of debug lines, like:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.248.xx [172.16.248.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
etc
```

Is there a way to redirect these lines to the file?

Answer (score 64):

You have to change the order of the redirections on the command line:

```
ssh -v root@172.16.248.xx >result.txt 2>&1
```

or just:

```
ssh -v root@172.16.248.xx 2>result.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the [docs](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#E) you can use the `-E` option to store debug logs in file:

```
 -E log_file
         Append debug logs to log_file instead of standard error.
```

Comment: Welcome Bhoodha! Consider improving your question putting some more context. For example adding the reference to the manual pages: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1

Comment: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#E

Answer (score -7):

Apparently the best way to save this "hidden" debug output to the file is by using logsave:

```
logsave result.txt ssh -v root@172.16.248.xx
```

Comment: Not at all necessary. It's not "hidden" debug info. It's STDERR, which you're redirecting to STDOUT. STDOUT is what you're redirecting, but you're doing this *after* you set STDERR to write to the same file that STDOUT was writing to (the console). That is why salva's answer should work.